# How to disable CSRF for a plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I developed a CakePHP 3 plugin that has to handle POST requests without a CSRF token.

In the application where I use the plugin I apply the middleware to the root scope.

```php
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
        'httpOnly' => true
    ]));

    $routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
...
```

How can I disable the middleware for the plugin?

I tried `$this->addPlugin(\My\Plugin::class, ['middleware' => false])` but that didn't work.

Or is the Plugin responsible to disable the CSRF middleware?

Comment: _Where_ and _how_ do you register the routes for the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to load the plugin routes in `Application::bootstrap()`.

```php
$this->addPlugin(\My\Plugin::class, ['routes' => true]);
```

According to the [cake book](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/plugins.html#plugin-hook-configuration) routes, bootstrap, middleware and console hooks are disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
// In Application::bootstrap()
use ContactManager\Plugin as ContactManagerPlugin;

// Use the disable/enable to configure hooks.
$plugin = new ContactManagerPlugin();

$plugin->disable('middleware');
$this->addPlugin($plugin);
```

Comment: Is there any problem with this solution?